# ocrmypdf not able to find tesseract path

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract, ocrmypdf

The issue is that ocrmypdf pdf not able to find the tesseract-engine path even though I have added in the environment variables. So I need a quick solution is it possible to externally add path to the ocrmypdf.ocr() function in python.

Even imported the every required library but still it's not working
Need a quick solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the path in your python script, e.g.:

```
import pytesseract

# some code to process the image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

#some other code for ocr
```

But this should not necessary, if you have in your system environment the pathname, e.g:

```
C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR
```

and create a variable in your system environmement, too.
[image]

Comment: yeah thanks got it. It's the issue with the system it did'nt properly added the application

Comment: how to do that?